# How to download files to multiple laptops at once with dynamic IPs

Tags: networking, server, puppet, education, chef

I work at a company that teaches kids how to code, we often travel to the school sites to do the camp and have our own fleet of laptops that we bring with us.

I have the laptops in a Deep Freeze state.

Is there any way to get a sort of "Master/Puppet" software such as "Chef", "Puppet" or "Ansible" to work on these laptops.

We will be going from school to school and the IPs of the laptops will constantly be changing

All I need it for is to download some video game assets from a remote server as well as some small programs here and there, nothing too big.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are they running?

Comment: Could you describe more in detail which problems you are facing with 'software such as "Chef", "Puppet" or "Ansible" to work on these laptops'? Your question is very broad.